# O que são esses dois pontos no começo de uma URL em CSS?

Tags: css, html5

Criei uma folha css, linkada ao html para formatar o mesmo, depois de muitas tentativas o código só aceito a formatação depois que eu a deixei assim:

```
h1 {
    background-image: url(../img/sobre-background.jpg);
}
```

no entanto não entendo os 2 pontos no começo, sendo que não tem uma pasta ou caminho com esses 2 pontos!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `../` volta 1 nível na árvore de diretórios, Assim como `../../` volta 2 níveis etc.

O caminho `url(../img/sobre-background.jpg)` irá procurar o arquivo `sobre-background.jpg` dentro da pasta `img` dentro da *pasta-mãe* da pasta do documento que está chamando o arquivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Os dois pontos é para indicar que vai descer um nível na hierarquia de pastas.

Provavelmente seu css está em uma pasta css:

> css
>
> > arquivo.css
>
> index.html
>
> img
>
> > imagem.jpg

quando vc dá o comando **../** você indica que está descendo um nível na pasta e indo na pasta **img**.

Answer (score 1):

Isso se chama um **caminho (*path*) relativo**!

O que você fez (`url(../img/sobre-background.jpg)`) irá considerar a imagem no diretório anterior.

Suponha que você tenha a seguinte estrutura de diretório:

> - diretório principal
>
>   - index.html
>   - css
>
>     - main.css
>   - img
>
>     - sobre-background.jpg

Se você usar os dois pontos em uma url do CSS, significa que ele irá voltar um diretório.

Para saber mais, sugiro que leia:
-> http://www.nce.ufrj.br/ginape/cursohtml/conteudo/ligacoes/absrel.htm